# pandas move to correspondent column based on value of other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Im trying to move the f1_am, f2_am, f3_am to the correspondent column based on the values of f1_ty, f2_ty, f3_ty

I started adding new columns to the dataframe based on unique values from the _ty using sets, but I'm trying to figure it out how to move the _am values to were it belongs

Looked for the option of group by and pivot but the result exploded my mind....

I would appreciate some guidance.

Below the code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data = { 
  'mem_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
, 'date_inf': ['01/01/2019', '01/01/2019', '01/01/2019', '02/01/2019', '02/01/2019', '02/01/2019'] 
, 'f1_ty': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'GHI'] 
, 'f1_am': [100, 20, 57, 44, 15, 10] 
, 'f2_ty': ['DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'ABC', 'XYZ'] 
, 'f2_am':[20, 30, 45, 66, 14, 21]
, 'f3_ty': ['XYZ', 'GHI', 'OPQ', 'OPQ', 'XYZ', 'DEF'] 
, 'f3_am':[20, 30, 45, 66, 14, 21]
}



df = pd.DataFrame (data) 

#distinct values in columns using sets
distinct_values = sorted(list(set(df['f1_ty'])|set(df['f2_ty'])|set(df['f3_ty'])))


# add distinct values as new columns in the DataFrame
new_df = df.reindex(columns = np.append( df.columns.values, distinct_values))
```

So this would be my starting point and my wanted result.
[image: starting point]

[image]

Comment: do you need: `m=df.set_index(['mem_id','date_inf'])` and then 
`m[sorted(m.columns,key=lambda x:x.split('_')[1])].reset_index()` ? *commenting since the requirement is not much clear to me*

Comment: added pictures for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try, thanks for the interesting problem (rename colujmns to make compatible to [`wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) followed by [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) while [`dropping`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) extra levels:

```
m=df.set_index(['mem_id','date_inf']).rename(columns=lambda x: ''.join(x.split('_')[::-1]))
n=(pd.wide_to_long(m.reset_index(),['tyf','amf'],['mem_id','date_inf'],'v')
.droplevel(-1).set_index('tyf',append=True).unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(m.index))
```

---

```
final=n.droplevel(0,axis=1).rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()
print(final)
```

---

```
  mem_id    date_inf  ABC  DEF  GHI  OPQ  XYZ
0      A  01/01/2019  100   20    0    0   20
1      B  01/01/2019   20   30   30    0    0
2      C  01/01/2019   57   45    0   45    0
3      A  02/01/2019   44    0   66   66    0
4      B  02/01/2019   14    0   15    0   14
5      C  02/01/2019    0   21   10    0   21
```

Comment: Thank you, Ill keep wide_to_long near forever.

Comment: I have only one problem when one of the funds is repeated, i get this error

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape,